# B2C post_logout_redirect_uri not working with SAML

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We're working with Entra B2C as the IdP for some SAML apps. We're using custom policies. All works correctly for login/logout for individuals whose primary identity is in the B2C, but there is a group of users who get logged in via federated login, so I want to redirect them after login to do that...

The original logout URL is

https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml2_testsv/samlp/sso/logout

When I add the request for a redirect, as follows:

https://domain.b2clogin.com/domain.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_signup_signin_saml2_testsv/samlp/sso/logout&post_logout_redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fv2.0%2Flogout

I get a "bad request" error message.

I have added the redirect URL to the valid ones for the application.

Thanks in advance.